# Extract part of a string with XML package

Tags: r, xml

I am using the XML R Package. After extract the XML code in the object 'doc' with the code:

```
doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE),
```

Imagine that I have simply this XML code in 'doc':

```
<p> interesting <a> not interesting </a> interesting2 </p>
```

I want to extract only the 'interesting' part (i.e. all but the 'a' part).

I tried expressions similars to:

```
interesting <- xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue)
```

which, obviously, extract all the content of doc. How can I extract only the string of text interesting to me (i.e. 'interesting interesting2').

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

`//*[not(self::a)]/text()` will exclude `a`

Comment: Thanks waterling! Please, see below!!